# How do I get these queries using the group in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

How do I get these queries using the group in a table? "SaveDate" even if the date in column I want to group by day. as follows:

```
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|Day|queryresult1|queryresult2|...|queryresult5|
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|1  |count       |count       |...|count       |
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|2  |count       |count       |...|count       |
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|...|...         |...         |...|...         |
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|...|...         |...         |...|...         |
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|...|...         |...         |...|...         |
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
|30 |count       |count       |...|count       |
+---+------------+------------+---+------------+
```

1-15 days to document data in the table's column savedate. How do I show 30 days?

```
Select 
(Select Count(*) from Document Where LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1) result1,
(Select Count(*) from Document Where LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and TutanakUserID is not null) as result2,
(Select Count(*) from Document Where LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and BayiEksik=0 and SahaEksik=0) as result3,
(Select Count(*) from Document Where LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and BayiEksik=1 and SahaEksik=0) as result4,
(Select Count(*) from Document Where LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and BayiEksik=1 and SahaEksik=1) as result5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series of CASE statements will do the trick:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LINEID=45 AND Esitlendi=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and TutanakUserID is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result2
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and BayiEksik=0 and SahaEksik=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result3
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and BayiEksik=1 and SahaEksik=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result4
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1 and BayiEksik=1 and SahaEksik=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result5
FROM Document
```

Since you've got some common criteria you can move them to WHERE clause:

Edit: I don't see a date field in your example, but if you have one in the table, to show records for every day you'll want a calendar table with every day listed:

```
SELECT SaveDate
     , COUNT(*) Result1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN TutanakUserID is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result2
     , SUM(CASE WHEN BayiEksik=0 and SahaEksik=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result3
     , SUM(CASE WHEN BayiEksik=1 and SahaEksik=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result4
     , SUM(CASE WHEN BayiEksik=1 and SahaEksik=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Result5
FROM CalTable a
LEFT JOIN Document b
     ON a.date = b.SaveDate
WHERE LineID=45 and Esitlendi=1
GROUP BY SaveDate
ORDER BY SaveDate
```

Comment: how are grouped according to each day? "SaveDate" column is not some days